# is this dynamic (column & table) PHP select query safe?

Tags: php, web, pdo, sql-injection

Tables and Columns names cannot be bind using PDO ->bindParam(), but I am sure more than one would love to be able to. It is a little late, but I wrote this earlier and so far it works. I am kind of new to php, and would like to know what you think and if it is safe.

```
$type = "defaultTableName";
$sortBy = "defaultColumnName";
$orderBy = "ASC";

//whitelisting unsafe input
if(isset($_GET['orderBy'])&&($_GET['orderBy']=="ASC"||$_GET['orderBy']=="DESC"))
    $orderBy = $_GET['orderBy'];
$tableNames = array("defaultTableName", "tableName2", "tableName3");
$unsafeType= $_GET['type']; <---unsafe input
$unsafeSortBy = $_GET['sortBy']; <---unsafe input

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //if input is not valid this will use default table to render a table in html.
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("DESCRIBE $type");
$stmt->execute();
$table_fields = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

 //Whitelisting user input against table names (will require table names updates)
    if (in_array($unsafeType, $tableNames)) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("DESCRIBE $unsafeType");
    $stmt->execute();
    $table_fields = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

 ///Whitelisting the column name to sort by against the description of the table.
        if (in_array($unsafeSortBy, $table_fields)) {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $unsafeType ORDER BY $unsafeSortBy $orderBy");
    }
    else    {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $type ORDER BY $sortBy $orderBy");
    }
} else {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $type ORDER BY $sortBy $orderBy");
}
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
 }
```

Only problem I see is that you will need to add/delete/change the table name array when you change the tables. I have a small/medium application in mind, not very complex.

Note: I am also terrible editing in stackoverflow, so if you know a way to make it nicer go ahead and edit or let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's not safe. You're directly placing user-submitted data into the query string. **ANYTIME** you do that you're vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

However, since you can't use placeholders for those particular values, you'll have to escape the data yourself with `pdo::quote`, e.g.

```
$safeType = $pdo->quote($_GET['type']);
```

just because it's a table name or a sort-by clause value doesn't mean it can't be injected. ANY user data going into a string that's not been quoted/escaped or inserted via placeholders is an attack vector.

Comment: I finally got it...before i get to validate it. It can be escaped.